# Make one http call based on previous' result

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to make two HTTP calls (first GET and second POST), the second based on result of the first.

Here's the response from the GET:

```json
{
    "weekNbr": "34-2017",
    "startDate": "2017-09-16",
    "endDate": "2017-09-22"
}
```

This response will then be manipulated and sent as a POST request with the following JSON:

```json
{
    "weekNbr": 34, (as received above)
    "year": 2017 (as received above)
}
```

One Solution:

```
http.get(url1).pipe(
    map(do your maipulation)
).subscribe(
    (newlyCreatedObject) => {
        return http.post(url2,newlyCreatedObject);
    }
);
```

But I don't think it's the correct way.

**NOTE:**
These calls are supposed to be made in a single service. If there are any rxjs operators to do the same, it'd be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`flatMap/mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) operator to make two HTTP requests, one depending on the other.

Like:

```
http.get(data).flatMap(res => {
    // res is response of Get
    // manipulate the data and passed in post call
    return http.post(data);
})
.map(res => {})
.catch(e => {});
```

Comment: Mergemap is used to make two simultaneous calls as far as I know. Not sure about flatMap/switchMap, though. Also, i need to manipulate my data from get and then feed it to the post call. So that requires some extra manipulation which I don’t think is recommended in operators like map(made for minor filtering/updation) of data!

Comment: `mergeMap` is just the new name of `flatMap`. within `mergeMap` you can do the manipulations you want. Otherwise, if you prefer this style, use `http.get(data).map(res => // do the manipulations).flatMap(res => {
    return http.post(data);
})`

Answer (score 0):

i have prepare this dummy service :

```
import {of, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
/**
 * Dummy get observable.
 */
export class MyService {

  getInformation$(): Observable<{foo:string}> {
    return of({foo:'bar'});
  }

  postInformation$(params:{foo:string}): Observable<any> {
    return of({
      fooUpperCase: params.foo.toUpperCase() // Stupid transformation for demonstration only
    });
  }

  main() {
    this.getInformation$().pipe(
      flatMap(data => this.postInformation$(data)) // receive each next and return new observable. 
    ).subscribe(console.log);
  }
}

new MyService().main();
```

For demonstration only, i have switch http observable to dummy `of` observable.

[live sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gziywe)

Comment: I think this would work. Thanks mate! Also, i want the POST data(which is returned) in a component. So i am thinking of using a resolver to fetch the data(the main() function would be in it)! But is it recommended to have that kind of data manipulation in a resolver? Or as you used in the post call( since its gonna be in service.ts file where data manipulation is not recommended )?